# Is there something in Python that is similar to "want" in Perl

Tags: python, perl

In Perl there is a way to find out what context a function is called in - whether it's a list or scalar context - or even finer granularity. See [wantarray](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/wantarray) and the [want module](https://metacpan.org/pod/Want).

Is there something similar in Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Python doesn't have the scalar/array distinction that Perl does. Values are simply bound to names with no regard for the type of the value.

The closest analogy I can think of would be something like

```
x += y
```

This is desugared as `x.__iadd__(y)`, so the method `__iadd__` could examine the type of its argument `y` if it wanted to. For example, even though `list.__iadd__` *doesn't* do this, it could theoretically have been defined to allow things like

```
x = []
x += 9  # x == [9]; append a non-iterable argument
x += [11, 12]  # x == [9, 11, 12]; extend with an iterable argument
```

Comment: Interesting! I'll look more into this desugaring thing. Does it apply to assignment too somewhere?

Comment: Ah! I love the term `desugared`. I'll have to use that!

Comment: "Syntactic sugar" refers to syntax that isn't strictly necessary; it can be replaced ("desugared") without affecting the semantics at all. For example, `x += y` is equivalent to `x = x + y` if `x.__iadd__` isn't defined, so the meaning of the syntax depends on the type of `x`, not just the 6-character string `x += y`.

Comment: (What I meant to say, is that I think I used the term too loosely here.)